# How to use python to write SUBTOTAL formula to excel

Tags: python, excel, excel-formula

I need to use python to write SUBTOTAL formula into excel sheet.

I tried to use openpyxl library with the code bellow:

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('Main.xlsx')
ws = wb['Sheet1']

cell = ws['B11']
cell.value = "=SUBTOTAL(9;B2:B10)"

wb.save('Main.xlsx')
```

(the semi comma in the excel formula is because in our work we do not use Eng localization)

Then, when I tried to open the excel file, I got an error "We found a problem with some content".

But if I wrote the same text, yet without the "=", then I opened the excel file and wrote the "=" into the text prepared by python by myself, the formula works.

Please, do you know where the problem is? Is there any solutions how to do it?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('Main.xlsx')
ws = wb['Sheet1']

cell = ws['B11']
cell.value = "=SUBTOTAL(9,B2:B10)"
cell.data_type = 'f'

wb.save('Main.xlsx')
```

you can set data_type attribute set to 'f', Excel will recognize the value in the cell as a formula and will calculate it when the sheet is opened

Comment: Well, thank you! I spent more than two hours searching the solutions. I tried everything, but didn't try to write the formula with comma. I'm ashamed. Thanks again!